# regression of non normal data

Tags: multiple-regression

I had to develop a multiple regression linear equation for my multivariate non normal data of physio-chemical parameters with N=100 observations.So I fed my data into SPSS and got the following result:

$R=.723$ , $R^2=.523$ , $adjR^2=.513$ , $S=51.03$ , $ F=14.707$ , $sig=.000$

So my question is whether I can go ahead with this model given that the data is not normal?
Is Central Limit Theorem applicable in this case?

Comment: It is irrelevant whether the data are normal: indeed, unless all coefficients (apart from the intercept) are zero, the data are unlikely to be normal in any regression model.  What matters is the distribution of the *errors* in the model.  Have you run the usual graphical diagnostics to explore the distribution of the model *residuals*?  If not, then please do that at once, and then search our site for posts about regression residuals and review them in light of what you see.

Comment: Just to add on what @whuber said - you can look at [UCLA's regression diagnostics using SPSS](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/webbooks/reg/chapter2/spssreg2.htmhttp://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/webbooks/reg/chapter2/spssreg2.htm), section 2.2